# How to prevent a modal that is placed absolute centered from touching the top of the broswer when only height of screen is changing

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

So Currently, I am creating a modal that is centered in the middle of the page by position absolute. The problem is when I adjust my broswer height and only the height, it will push the modal up and touch the top of the screen and even go pass it. I just want to know how to stop that from helping.

```
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```
.callLogForm__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 55rem;
  max-height: 65rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 11px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```
Parent of modal-container

 <>
      {navRoutes.includes(location.pathname) ? <NavBar /> : null}
      <main
        className={
          sideMenuRoutes.includes(location.pathname)
            ? "main-container flex-box"
            : "main-container"
        }
      >
        {sideMenuRoutes.includes(location.pathname) ? <Sidemenu /> : null}
        <Routes />
      </main>
      <Modal />
    </>
```

[image: Problem One]

This is what is doing when I shrink the browswer's height and only the height.

Answer (score 2):

You could use viewport unit for the height.

Viewport units are based on the dimensions of the viewport (width and height of the visible browser page, excluding toolbars, search bars).

- vh - viewport height
- vw - viewport width

1vh - 1% of viewport's height.

So in your modal you can do something like,

```
.modal-container {
    ...
    height: 75vh;
    ....
}
```

It will make sure that the height of the modal is always 75% of the screen's height.

Also you wanna handle the overflowing scenario. So that the content inside the modal will always be visible to the user.

Try this,

```
.modal-container {
    ...
    height: 75vh;
    overflow-y: auto
    ....
}
```

You can also use "vw" (viewport width) to the modal container to control the width in the same way.

Comment: Just curious, why height: 75vh but not 100vh?

Comment: It's just a random value. Using 100vh would touch the screen edges. With some reduced values, we can have a nice gap between edges of the screen and the modal. :-)

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/FcI4m8YkBUZCHWudHD/giphy.gif I gave your solution a try, it doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this. So that we can test it live and we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flex property to align content in the center of the model so it will automatically adjust the browser height. Please check the below example

```
.modal-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ashok-kannan-dev/pen/jOYBwRe

Comment: I tried this method before and doesn’t give the solution I need. The method you provided does set the modal content center. However, when I adjust my browser height, it will shrink the modal-content. I just want the modal-content to be centered but does shrink instead it will just show a scroll bar for user.

Comment: @reacttesting I think you are flex property placement is wrong you can add a parent of the content div also add the height: 100%

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/FcI4m8YkBUZCHWudHD/giphy.gif This what it is doing and I am using your code. Am I missing anything?

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/UsgjUGs6U4wSzT7w5h/giphy.gif I just want something like this.

Comment: @reacttesting Please share your modal box working coding to https://stackblitz.com/ I will check and help to fix this issue.

Comment: @AshokK https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z8tqr4?file=src/Content.js here is the link. When I resize it, it just push it up which is not what I want.

Comment: Hey @reacttesting, Just tried with 90vh on that. It works the way that you need I guess. Check this, https://i.postimg.cc/qq9qRQvn/Screenshot-2022-03-26-at-10-24-03.png

Comment: Have you try resizing the height of the screen ?

Comment: Please check this one https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wfqf8r?file=src%2FModal.css
Screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/24712617?key=30c0784f958015b30e5f3d74cfb786ac